# Zoom HTML in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, zooming, jtextpane

I'm using a simple `JTextPane` inside a `JScrollPane` to show my application's manual (simple HTML with a few pictures and a bunch of links), and can't find a way to scale this thing to make the application DPI-aware.

I tried CSS, but nothing, then I tried overriding the paint method but it becomes impossible to click on things because they remain in their original position.
Is there some way to zoom it?

Comment: http://java-sl.com/Scale_In_JEditorPane.html

Comment: That's exactly what I adapted

Comment: *"I tried CSS, but nothing"* I see that, from the code you didn't post.

Comment: html{zoom:120%} is ignored by java. I think it doesn't support CSS3

Comment: *"I think it doesn't support CSS3"*  Swing Java does not support a lot of CSS (let alone CSS 3).  But that is not the only way to skin this cat.

Comment: So, do you know how to do it? Do I redo the manual using JLabels inside a long ass JPanel stuck into a JScrollPane? I'd like to avoid that :)

Comment: Try `html{size:120%}`, and if that doesn't work for you, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).